# Reversing PyArmor + Pyinstaller

Tags: python, deobfuscation

Created an application, protected by PyArmor and used pyinstaller. I'm trying to reverse engineer it. So far I've decompiled the exe into pyc files but it's still pyarmor encrypted I can only see the loading of the encrypted bytes.

1. Is there a way to decrypt PyArmor?
2. If not, it's my understanding it decrypts at runtime, how could I catch the unencrypted portion? I've been trying to use Ollydbg but can't figure out exactly how it works.
3. The program prints a Hello World but I can't seem to even find the instruction or the string in reference strings, any idea why or how to do it?

Comment: In my opinion to find where your code is, Don't just use simple `print hello world!` instead use an API function and set break-point on that particular api. if you use an unique API function you will stop on your real-original API code that will return to your code.